# Tabhost + fragments

Tags: android

I've seen applications that contain panel with tabs that don't lead user to another activities. I guess, this is where TabHost + Fragment elements are used.

Could you give your assumptions/caveats/links on implementing this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can make use of ViewPager.

First include the ViewPager in your layout (you can use the one in the compatibility package for old versions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To load several Fragments into a ViewPager, you have to implement a FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Fragment fragment1;
    private Fragment fragment2;

    public ChartPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        fragment1 = new MyFragment();
        fragment2 = new MyFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment1;
            case 1:
                return fragment2;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Title 1";
            case 1:
                return "Title 2";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you set this adapter to the ViewPager:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MyActivity.this);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't seen this approach. Why is it, if so, better than Tabhost + fragments ?

Comment: It's Not better, but it provides the swipe functionality, which is a very smooth way to switch between pages. Also, its implementation is very straighforward.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage with using `TabHost` is that you can place it anywhere. It can be implemented as a `View` itself.

Here are 2 two good links I found:

[Android Tabs with Fragments](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/)

[Blog Post](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `TabActivity`, something like this:

```
public class NavigationBarActivity extends TabActivity (
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTabs();
    }

    private void setTabs(){
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost    
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;           // Reusable TabSpec for each tab    
        Intent intent;                  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        // tab 1------------------------------
        View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null, false);
        ImageView tabImage = (ImageView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);
         TextView tabText = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

        // set icon
        tabImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab1);

        // set tab text
        tabText.setText(R.string.tab1);

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)    
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity1.class);    
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ta1");
        spec.setIndicator(tabView);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // tab 2 -----------------------------------------
        tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, null, false);
        tabImage = (ImageView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);
        tabText = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

        // set icon
        tabImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab2); 

        // set tab text
        tabText.setText(R.string.tab2);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ChatListActivity.class);    
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        spec.setIndicator(tabView);                  
        spec.setContent(intent);    
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if(getTabHost().getCurrentTab() == 0) {
            // WE are on tab1 ...
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated. Its usage is discouraged.